# What's the proper way to import mods in other files in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am writing a Rust project and I want to use multiple mods. The src directory has files:`main.rs`, `default.rs`, `difficult.rs`.
The `default.rs` has:

```
pub struct Info {...}
pub fn f(...) {...}
```

and adding `mod default`, I can directly use `default::Info` and `default::f`.
But I want to use `Info` in `difficult.rs` and I add `mod default` into `difficult.rs`, then it gets error which says that `default` is not found.
How should I fix this?

Comment: mod is used to declare to the build system that a module exists. It has to be declared for every module, but only once. In main is fine.

Comment: So how should I use `Info` in `difficult.rs`?

Comment: You would need `use default;` to directly use `Info`. Or to access it with `default::Info`

Answer (score 0):

> How should I fix this?

You might want to read the book? The solution [is at section 7.4](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-04-bringing-paths-into-scope-with-the-use-keyword.html). Rust is *not* a language which is easy to learn, and learning rust by osmosis or random walking tends to be a frustrating and unsuccessful endeavour.

I would very strongly recommend reading the book cover to cover at least once.

Anyway `use` is how you "import" things into the local scope.

`mod` is how you *declare* a module. If you use `mod` multiple times for the same file, you're essentially creating copies of the modules, which the compiler will see as two unrelated modules with unrelated types.

Comment: I have read this, but I still do not know how to use struct defined in other mod in a file that is not `main.rs`.

Comment: This book mainly talks about how to define a mod in multiple times not use it in other files.

Comment: There is no fundamental difference between a single file and multiple files. As far as rustc is considered, `mod foo;` expands to `mod foo { include!("foo.rs"); }` (or or `foo/mod.rs`). 7.5 also explains multiple-files scenarios. And [7.2 provides a cheatsheet](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-02-defining-modules-to-control-scope-and-privacy.html#modules-cheat-sheet).

Comment: [Here's an example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a9eb9aa29192b65a03159d7d17a233af).